# How to call action method from Javacript inside the Visuaforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

this working fine but I want to add confirmation window for OK or Cancel.
OK means call the NewCase action from script and cancel mean close the confirmation page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CaseController" action={!NewCase}>
    <script>
    theQueryString = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
    document.location = '/' + theQueryString;
    </script>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with page `action`. For this, you have to call actionFunction from javascript like that:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CaseController">
  <apex:form id="caseform" >
     <apex:actionFunction action="{!NewCase}" name="createNewCase" rerender="caseform"/>
  </apex:form>
  <script>
    if(confirm('are you sure?'))
    {
      createNewCase();
    }
    else
    {
      theQueryString = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
      document.location = '/' + theQueryString;
    }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Great!!! This is working fine.  The only issue is when it execute the true condition it should refresh the screen to validate that the action really called. and it did, if i refresh the screen it show the new value.   I have added "document,location = '/' + theQueryString but it sees the old screen.

Comment: actionFunction does ajax call, thats why page not refreshed. but one thing you can do here, you can add rerender property in actionFuntion page. This refresh your page partially. Read out this property from here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

Comment: I updated the answer with rerender property.

Comment: i added rerender and id in form and now it show blank screen.... (:-( almost there...

Comment: Can you please paste your code here. Then i will be able to help you.

Comment: please see with rerender but still i need to refresh...

Comment: Why you need refresh? Rerender should work.

Comment: I need to refresh because on the Opportunity I also changed one the fields and this fields need to see by the user the it was changed after createNewCase was called and execute.  
The above code works but changes are showing when i manually refresh the page.

Comment: You don't need to refresh the page. You can handle this thing with rendered property. Please read out this example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm.